# Call to MKL_SDNSCSR of intell MKL failing

Tags: fortran, intel-mkl

I just dowloaded MKL in intend to try its sparse BLAS, the first thing I tried was the conversion of full matrix to sparse one with MKL_SDNSCSR

Here my code:

```
implicit none

real::A(2,5)
integer::job(8)
INTEGER::  info,n=2,m=5
INTEGER      ja(10), ia(6)
REAL          acsr(10)

A(1,:)=(/1, 0 ,1,0,2/)
A(2,:)=(/2,0,0,0,1/)

job=0
job(1)=0
job(2)=1
job(3)=1
job(4)=2
job(5)=10
job(6)=1

print*,A
print*,job

call mkl_sdnscsr(job,n,m,A,m,acsr,ja,ia,info)

end
```

It gives the following error:

```
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 1 was incorrect on entry to MKL_SDNSCSR.
```

What did I did wrong?

Best

Comment: I don't know this routine and don't have easy access to MKL at this second, but a quick google says the fifth argument is wrong - it is the leading dimension of the matrix A, which should be N, not M, in your case - or even better Size( A, Dim = 1 ). Can't test if this is what is causing your problem, though.

Comment: it s the first argument the problem, but it look all right too me

Comment: As I said I can't test it. Fix the things that you can see are wrong, and see if that fixes the whole problem - it may be that the definitions of the different arguments are not orthogonal. Have you tried what I suggest?

Comment: Yes I tried, it gave the same error

Answer (score 0):

I see no problems with this example. I tried the MKL v.2020 on win64.
here is the output I obtained:

```
   1.000000       2.000000      0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00   1.000000    
  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00   2.000000       1.000000    
           0           1           1           2          10           1
           0           0
```